# UIImageView autoresizingMask behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a view tableview which display custom cells. Those cells have a UIImageView which need to be scaled if the device is in landscape mode.

I set the `autoresizingMask` of the tableView to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, did the same for my custom cells and the UIImageView.

**My problem** is that setting `autoresizingMask` for the UIImageView changes the frame of the view without any rotation of the device needed.

This is my initialisation code for my UIImageView.

```
- (UIImageView *)bigImageView
{
  if (!_bigImageView)
  {
    _bigImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){2, [self.header getHeight], 272, 272}];
    [_bigImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"]];

    [_bigImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [_bigImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  }
  return _bigImageView;
}
```

The width should be **272** but changes automatically to **232**.

The result expected with `autoresizingMask` **should be:**
[image: TableView in blue, UIImageView in red]

**But I get:**

[image: don't mind the shadow]

The ratio is not respected anymore.

Comment: Since you are creating UIImageView in your code you should check at which moment do you add it as a subview. What is the value of .frame of your view at the moment of adding it? This value becomes the reference boundary for your flexible width.

Comment: I add it as a subview in `- (id)initWithStyle: ...` I put a NSLog right after adding it. At first the width is 272 but it changes afterward to 239.

Comment: There might be several reasons for that. You might have set accessoryType or accessoryView? Or added to improper view? Are you adding it to contentView or backgroundView? You should do some experiments like setting UIImageView frame width to UIView's width. Of course you could always set autoresizing mask to 0 and make something like `bigImageView.frame.size.width = self.contentView.frame.size.width` in your `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because every cell starts with a height of 44 points. You can check that in the init.

Maybe you can correct the size of the cell elements in `drawRect:` or in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Should returning a right value in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` prevent that?

Comment: No. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't pass its information to the init method. You can try it with NSLog print outs.